# Magento Cron reindexing issue

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex

We are facing an strange issue that products in listing pages are not showing in frontend. we are importing products from zoho and we have setup crons as update by schedule. Suddenly products got disappeared in listings page and there is no logs reported but when we reindex manually the products are showing.Does anyone faced this kind of issue , we are using magento 2.2.5 version.when we index catalog search, products are showing.can anyone know where to debug and to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. pls make sure your cron are running. After that, you can go to table "cron_schedule" check column "job_code" and "status" view time running. So, I think it is not schedule finished on your case. Just waiting it :)
2. You should change indexer from "update by schedule" to "update on save" because when you import product, it will pass over save. So, it will automatic reindex.

Comment: hii, our crons are running and i have checked in cron_schedule , and we are using mirasvit asynchronous indexer module for indexing, they said to change from update on save to update by schedule.